# YouTube Api OATH access token

Tags: oauth-2.0

I want to make a bot that will upload the videos from hard disk to YouTube. I have written the code already but there is a problem. I have to make the authorization manually by logging in to the Google account which gives me an access token, valid for only 1 hour. Now the trouble is the bot wont be able to login to the account and I am unable to use the access token after an hour. I heard about the refresh token but not sure how it works, can you help me with this? The perfect scenario would be having the access token through "Client_id" and "Secret_Key" (I should not have to login)

```
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setClientId(YOUTUBE_CLIENT_ID);
$client->setClientSecret(YOUTUBE_CLIENT_SECRET);
$client->setAccessToken(???);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So finally got a hint from ChatGPT :)
I had to add these two lines. Didn't know the "setPromt" function existed!

```
$client->setPrompt('consent');
$client->setAccessType('offline');
```